# YAGPDB how to make a reaction ticket

Tags: discord

I am implementing a YAGPDB bot and I need to create a ticket by a specific reaction on the bot message, how would that be done? I know it is possible to create a ticket with a command but it would be good if we could react to it, I was trying to create a custom command that uses "reaction" as a trigger but it was activating on literally all server reactions in any channel.

Comment: I avoided this issue by adding custom emojis to my server, then made those emojis tied to reaction commands. Hence, when an embed popped up, the bot generated the reactions I wanted on the embed, and then the user could click the reaction they wanted. But note, that if you tie the command to the reaction, ANY TIME the reaction is used, the command will occur, unless you tie it explicitly to the embed message ID.